# Inserting multiple datas to database that is populating using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form that I want save all multiple datas to my database but the `<div> class="items"</div>` is populating so here is my php code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/water/save_items' ?>" method="post">
<input id="uid" name="uid" value="5" type="hidden">
<div class="items">
    <input name="pid" value="1" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="6" type="hidden">
    <input name="pid" value="12" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="9" type="hidden">
    <input name="pid" value="11" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="56" type="hidden">
    <input name="pid" value="10" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="14" type="hidden">
    <input name="pid" value="14" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="4" type="hidden">
    <input name="pid" value="1" type="hidden"><input name="item" value="17" type="hidden">
</div>
<button id="checkout" type="button" class="btn btn-success product-button">Checkout</button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function save_items()
{
   $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
   $array = $this->input->post();
   $this->load->model('product_model');
   if(!empty($array))
   {
       foreach($array as $pid => $item) 
       {
          $this->product_model->addProduct($uid,$pid,$item);
       }
   }

   redirect('water/products');
}
```

product_model.php

```
public function addProduct($uid, $pid, $item)
{
   $data = array('uid'=>$uid, 'pid'=>$pid, 'item'=>$item);
   $this->db->insert('cart',$data);
}
```

I have an idea to save the uid but I don't know how to get and save the values of "pid" and "item" from the form

expected database value should be like this

```
uid     pid     item
 5      1       6
 5      12      9
 5      11      56
 5      10      14
 5      14      4
 5      1       17
```

Comment: 'pid[]' and 'item[]' in name attribute, instead 'pid' and 'item'- make arrays, and process them....

Comment: use `pid[]` for input name.

Comment: how do i get the pid and item and iterate?

Comment: loop them on your model and pass it to database.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new in codeigniter and php

Comment: $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
  $pid = $this->input->post('pid[]');
  $item = $this->input->post('item[]');
  $this->load->model('product_model');
  
   foreach($pid as $pid[] => $item[]) 
   {
    $this->product_model->addProduct($uid,$pid[],$item[]);
   }
  is this right?

Comment: index.php/water/save_items - bad idea to use that. unless index.php is folder's name, which is weird

Comment: i haven't configure yet my url sorry

Comment: i already got it but something is wrong with the pid and item.. it is null when inserting to database but I echo it and it has values.. only uid has a value

Answer (score 0):

```
        $data = array(
        array(
        'title' => 'My title' ,
        'name' => 'My Name' ,
        'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
        'title' => 'Another title' ,
        'name' => 'Another Name' ,
        'date' => 'Another date'
        )
        );

        $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); 

        // Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

Comment: i have a problem inserting my pid and item they are both null. But the uid has a value

Comment: Make sure they are nullable fields.

Answer (score 0):

USE pid[] and item[] array instead of pid,item

```
<div class="items">
        <input name="pid[]" value="1" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="6" type="hidden">
        <input name="pid[]" value="12" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="9" type="hidden">
        <input name="pid[]" value="11" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="56" type="hidden">
        <input name="pid[]" value="10" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="14" type="hidden">
        <input name="pid[]" value="14" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="4" type="hidden">
        <input name="pid[]" value="1" type="hidden"><input name="item[]" value="17" type="hidden">
    </div>
```

// and do the following in your this function

```
public function save_items()
{
   $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
   $item_data = $this->input->post('item');
   $pid_data = $this->input->post('pid');
   $this->load->model('product_model');

 for($i = 0; $i < count($item_data); $i++)
    {
        $pid = $pid_data[$i];
        $item = $item_data[$i];
        $this->product_model->addProduct($uid,$pid,$item);
    }


   redirect('water/products');
}
```